# Probability, The order of speaking

Tags: probability

Six students, A,B,C,D,E,F, are to give speeches to the class. The order of speaking is determined by random selection. What is the probability that E will speak first?

Comment: Try to determine the number of orderings in which E appears first, then figure out the total number of orderings.  The ratio will give the desired result

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two ways of thinking about it.

The simple way is to say you are randomly picking one out of six so the probability is $1/6$

The other way is counting all the arrangements and see in how many of them $E$ is first.

Well it happens to be that you are having $6!$ arrangements and in $5!$ of  them $E$ is first.

Thus the probability is $\frac {6!}{5!}=1/6$

See if you can find another way to come up with the answer.